Exporting RDS Postgres snapshot to S3 error : The principal export.rds.amazonaws.com isn't allowed to assume the IAM role
I want to extract my postgres db snapshot (rds) to s3 to upload it to snowflake/redshift and I have this error :
The principal export.rds.amazonaws.com isn't allowed to assume the IAM role arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/service-role/export-rds-s3 or the IAM role arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/service-role/export-rds-s3 doesn't exist.
Bucket :
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExportPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/service-role/export-rds-s3"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

IAM Role has AmazonS3FullAccess permission and this trust relationship :
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "export.rds.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}

The rds and s3 are in the same region.
Am I don't something wrong here ?
